# Is it legal to use a const value captured in a lambda as a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer

Consider the following code, provided by a colleague:

```
#include <array>
#include <string>

int main() {
    const int size = 4;
    return [size]() {
      std::array<std::string, size> a; // *
      return a.size();
    }();
}
```

It's accepted by Clang 5.0.0 but rejected by GCC 7.2 with the error message for the starred line being:

```
error: '__closure' is not a constant expression
```

Which compiler is right?

Comment: It compiles with [gcc 8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gYcDnTD00qFoDUch).

Comment: I would have thought that should not compile but closures are turing out to be a mystery within a conundrum.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, CV qualifiers follow the by-copy capture. Hence, Clang is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is actually intuitive: any occurrence of a variable that doesn't necessitate a capture refers to the original variable. [[expr.prim.lambda]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#11):

> Every *id-expression* within the *compound-statement* of a
>   *lambda-expression* that is an odr-use of an entity captured by copy is
>   transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of
>   the closure type. [ Note: **An *id-expression* that is not an odr-use
>   refers to the original entity**, never to a member of the closure type.
>   […] — end note ]

Clearly, the declared `size` variable can be used in constant expressions, hence Clang is right.